# How can I have a dough attachment when I have a Dretec Handmixer?

Tags: bread

I have a Dretec Hand Mixer and as far as I can see it doesn't have additional attachments for sale online. Can I attach some other mixer's dough attachment onto it?

[image]

[image]

[image: Only attachments included]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK it's really difficult to knead dough with a hand mixer even if it comes equipped with dough hooks.

I was in your shoes a while ago too and after some research, found that it's basically useless for kneading dough. Unless you're Popeye, you're not going to be able to hold the mixer and the bowl steady enough for the dough to get kneaded. I ended up buying a KitchenAid.

Either spend the money on a stand mixer or just knead your doughs by hand.

Comment: If the hand mixer didn’t come with hooks, it probably wasn’t designed for the kind of mechanic stress / force required to knead dough.

Comment: See also  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11445/my-hand-mixer-came-with-dough-hooks-can-i-knead-dough-with-it

Comment: It is second kneading that is the hard one.